# Which social network profile pic appears in my contacts app on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, contacts

The individual contacts in my Contacts app have numerous social networks associated with them e.g. a Facebook profile and a Linkedin profile. They have a different pic for each social network.

How do I select which social network photo is used as the photo in the Calendar app?

Answer (score 1):

Click the existing photo or the blank 'add photo' icon.

You can pick a picture from the list of choices - or even just drag any image to that icon instead of clicking.
You then get a pan & zoom page to tweak how it will appear for the contact.

[image]

I think otherwise it just picks the first one it finds - some of my contacts have a map of their home location… hardly what I'd have chosen myself…

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to tell the contacts app "use the facebook profile ID."

Comment: I don't think that is possible - would break all kinds of sandboxing requirements imo. It's easy enough to simply drag their profile pic directly from FB in Safari right to that 'add photo' icon - doesn't need to even go via the desktop, just straight to it.